# Representing rich text in XML

Tags: xml, web-services

I have a paragraphs of text in the database, f.i.:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.

<b>Proin sed lacus id felis</b> bibendum posuere sed vitae mi.

<square-red> Nullam sit amet erat non tortor laoreet cursus.
```

I need to provision these as XML web service representation. In this case - 3 paragraphs of text with some well formed tags (as `<b>`), and also something that is completetly invalid (`<square-red>` without closing tag). Other possibilites include lists and link to images (for links I could use Atom's links element).

The client that receives this XML needs to know about styling (like bold), that there are 3 paragraphs and that some of them have special meeaning, i.e. the whole paragraph *have to* displayed in red color.

Is there any good format for representing such data in XML?
Are there any best practicies for representing rich text?

Answer (score 1):

I believe [XSL Formatting Objects](http://www.w3.org/TR/2006/REC-xsl11-20061205/#fo-section) or `XSL-FO` is designed for this purpose, but I have never seen it used by anyone so support may be limited. A standards-compliant approach would be better than an ad-hoc one in my opinion though, even if the standard is rarely-used.

Comment: I agree with a statement, but reading articles about XLS-FO is like reading a scary book. The same is for DocBook. I am thinking about using XHTML.